# Error 1004 when populating cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA procedure that worked as intended, then I commented it out to work on another procedure and now when I try the first procedure again, it doesn't work.  I'm trying to update cells in a row with values calculated in the code.  The code is below, stripped of anything that isn't directly involved in this problem.  The first procedure checks for a value change and if changed, it calls a validation procedure before the main 'Process_Utilization' procedure...that's where the problem is.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If Target.Address = Range("start_dt").Address Then
        'Verify_start_date
        Process_Utilization
    End If

    If Target.Address = Range("end_dt").Address Then
        'Verify_end_date
        Process_Utilization
    End If

ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub

Private Sub Process_Utilization()
' Declare variables
Dim r As Integer            'row counter

'The x_col variables below are used to store the column number of the referenced column
Dim tot_hrs_col As Integer
Dim cost_col As Integer
Dim tot_cost_col As Integer
Dim total_util_col As Integer

Dim avail_hrs As Double     'available hours, based on the date range
Dim total_hrs As Double     'total hours

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

'Set the column number variables equal to the number of their corresponding named cell
tot_hrs_col = Range("est_total_hours").Column
cost_col = Range("cost_hr").Column
tot_cost_col = Range("total_cost").Column
total_util_col = Range("total_util").Column

'******************************************************************************
' Bunch of code to calculate values for the variables
'******************************************************************************

‘ This line is executed and the cell populated properly
Cells(r, total_util_col).Value = total_hrs / avail_hrs
‘ ****** ERROR ON THE FOLLOWING LINE ********
Cells(r, tot_hrs_col).Value = total_hrs
 Cells(r, tot_cost_col).Value = total_hrs * Cells(r, cost_col).Value

'******************************************************************************
‘ More code
'******************************************************************************
End Sub
```

What is interesting is that the first 'write' line executes properly and it's the second that fails.  If I comment out the second, the third fails.  However if I comment out the first line, the second one works and the third fails, so it seems something is not being reset properly.  I've seen a lot of 1004 error threads but haven't found one that seems to speak to my issue.

Comment: I would say to qualify your cells but then first line wouldn't work either... are the values of your variables as you expect at time of error?

Comment: What is the value of `tot_hrs_col` during debug? (when it is yellow, put the mouse over it and wait for it to display value or add `Debug.Print tot_hrs_col` just before the error line and see value in Immediate Window)

Comment: they all use total_hrs, so i'd check the value of that variable 1st.

Comment: All of the values are as I would expect during debug: r=8, tot_hrs_col=8, total_hrs=36, avail_hrs=160, total_util_col=16.  It's very odd that it all used to work but now just the first one works.  I'm sure something small as I'm very new to VBA.

Comment: Hmm have you tried adding `application.enableevents=false` in `process utilization`? The `worksheet change` event may be hitting it causing it to begin anew.

Comment: Nothing changed in this procedure that I can think of.  It worked, so I commented out the call in the worksheet_change procedure and went to work on the date validation procedures.  After getting those to work, I uncommented the utilization procedure and got the errors, even after commenting out the date procedures.

Comment: I added the application.enableevents=false in the procedure and now I don't get the error but nothing happens; no cells are updated.  Is there a specific spot I should put it?

Comment: My fault. Add it above the first write then turn it back on below that or below the last write.

Comment: Yes, i think you're re-protecting the sheet after adding 1 value, from the change event on the sheet.

Comment: Good news - you guys hit it!  I was unprotecting / reprotecting the sheet in the util proc initially and then added the same commands to the change event because the date procs also need to change cells.  After commenting out the lines in the change event (and the newly added enable events line), the util proc works as expected.  However, if I comment out the commands in the util proc and leave them in the change event, I get the error again.  I'm confused why it won't work in the change event and seems redundant to replicate them in each proc. Thoughts?

Comment: Because the event is triggered everytime there's a change. Edit: you can use`enableevents=false` before the change then turn in back on but it's good to always have it on.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense.  I moved the unprotect / protect commands inside the "IF" statements on the change event and now all works as it should.  I knew it was something simple :)  Thank you both!!!

Comment: Oh duh. That's smarter ^_^ Glad to help.